# Counting all the wins in two columns using two columns?

Tags: mysql

Let's take this table for an example...

```
m_tid | m_tid2 | m_hteam_score | m_ateam_score
  2       5           69             30
  5       2           0               5
```

I'm bad at custom making tables, sorry...

So let's take this data, now `m_tid` and `m_tid2` are columns for TID's that are in a separate table of their own.

Now what I want to do, is collect the score for team id2 (or team id1) of all the scores... How would I count two columns for whether or not the team is on `m_tid` and `m_tid2`

I don't have a query made, but I wouldn't know how I would go about making a query for this anyways. :(

The expected results would be something like this

```
  m_tid | m_tid_score | m_tid2 | m_tidscore2
    5         35          2           69
```

Comment: From your sample data, what are your expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the total score for each team, here is one method using correlated subqueries:

```
select t.*,
       (coalesce((select sum(s.m_hteam_score) from scores s where s.m_tid = t.tid), 0) +
        coalesce((select sum(s.m_ateam_score) from scores s where s.m_tid2 = t.tid), 0)
       ) as totalscore           
from teams t;
```

Comment: Going to check this code real quick and see if it will work, be back in 5 minutes.

Comment: The code worked perfectly first try, I have to wait 4 minutes to select you as the "Answer" but thank you so much! I appreciate this very much, I didn't even know what "coalesce" was until I google'd it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select o.id, sum(case when y.m_tid = o.id then y.m_hteam_score 
                 when y.m_tid2 = o.id then y.m_ateam_score
                 else 0 end) score
from othertable o 
    join yourtable y on o.id in (y.m_tid, y.m_tid2)
group by o.id
```